# Data retrieval for Android from IBM Bluemix

Tags: android, mysql, ibm-cloud

I have a database hosted on IBM Bluemix. I am making use of Composedb for Mysql. How do i retrieve Json data from that db hosted online. Any insights on this would be useful.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: What did you do for it already?

Comment: Web application.